# To copy the files from a server to a local directory using python

Tags: python

I'm trying to write the copied files from the server to a local directory.But finding permission denied to access the folder.....I present my code here.Please correct my mistake....

Code:

```
from ftplib import FTP
import os
ip="ip address"
password='pwd'

ftp=FTP(ip)
ftp.login(username,password)
print "File List:"
files=ftp.dir()
mypath='C:\\test\\'+files
os.makedirs(mypath)
for filek in files: # Loop - looking for matching files
    file = open("%s" %(mypath), 'w')
    ftp.retrbinary('RETR '+ filek, file.write)
```

i'm getting the following error:

```
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\test\\November'
```

Comment: Are you sure that a) `C:\\test\\November` exists and b) you have the permission to write files to it?

Comment: i created that directory,it exists

Answer (score 0):

You create directories with `os.makedirs(mypath)` which you later want to write to as a file in `file = open("%s" %(mypath), 'w')`.

Either you edit `mypath='C:\\test\\'+files` to `mypath='C:\\test\\'` and then

```
for filek in files: # Loop - looking for matching files
    f = open("%s/%s" % (mypath, filek), 'w') # the slash will also work in windows!
    ftp.retrbinary('RETR '+ filek, file.write)
    f.close()
```

or you have to introduce filenames within your loop.

You also have to handle the case where `os.makedirs(mypath)` fails because the directory at `mypath` already exists. And please don't use `file` as variable name, it overwrites the builtin `file`.